# How to reduce number of requests to the Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When running the below with 200 Documents and 1 DocUser the script takes approx 5000ms according to AppStats. The culprint is that there is a request to the datastore for each lockup of the lastEditedBy (datastore_v3.Get) taking 6-51ms each.

What I'm trying do is to make something that makes possible to show many entities with several properties where some of them are derived from other entities. There will never be a large number of entities (<5000) and since this is more of an admin interface there will never be many simultaneous users.

I have tried to optimize by caching the DocUser entities but I am not able to get the DocUser key from the query above without making a new request to the datastore.

1) Does this make sense - is the latency I am experiencing normal?

2) Is there a way to make this work without the additional requests to the datastore?

*models.py*

```
class Document(db.Expando):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    lastEditedBy = db.ReferenceProperty(DocUser, collection_name = 'documentLastEditedBy')  
...

class DocUser(db.Model):
    user = db.UserProperty()
    name = db.StringProperty()  
    hasWriteAccess= db.BooleanProperty(default = False)
    isAdmin = db.BooleanProperty(default = False)
    accessGroups = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
...
```

*main.py*

```
$out = '<table>'   
documents = Document.all()
for i,d in enumerate(documents):        
    out += '<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>' % (d.title, d.lastEditedBy.name)
$out = '</table>'
```

Comment: Why are you looping on documents and then fetching all of them every time in the loop? Something is wrong with your main.py.

Comment: Sorry, error in my example code. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to prefetch all the docusers to make a lookup dictionary, with the keys being docuser.key() and values being docuser.name.

```
    docusers = Docuser.all().fetch(1000)
    docuser_dict = dict( [(i.key(), i.name) for i in docusers] )
```

Then in your code, you can get the names from the docuser_dict by using get_value_for_datastore to get the docuser.key() without pulling the object from the datastore.

```
    documents = Document.all().fetch(1000)
    for i,d in enumerate(documents):
        docuser_key = Document.lastEditedBy.get_value_for_datastore(d)
        last_editedby_name = docuser_dict.get(docuser_key)
        out += '<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>' % (d.title, last_editedby_name)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a typical anti-pattern. You can workaround this by:

- Prefetch all of the references. Please see [Nick's blog entry](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/01/ReferenceProperty-prefetching-in-App-Engine) for details.
- Use ndb. This module doesn't have ReferenceProperty. It has various goodies like [2 automatic caching layers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache), [asynchronous mechanism called tasklets](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async), etc. For more details, [see the ndb documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I now understand that the GAE datasore is a not as advanced and easy going as I thought first it was. I should probably use NBC instead but that would make it necessary to rewrite the whole application.

I cannot get Nick's code to work and I see that there are some comments on his blog that something is not working anymore. Have you  tested this recently?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cut instance-time, you can break a single synchronous query into multiple asynchronous queries, which can prefetch results while you do other work.  Instead of using Document.all().fetch(), use Document.all().run().  You may have to block on the first query you iterate on, but by the time it is done, all other queries will have finished loading results.  If you want to get 200 entities, try using 5 queries at once.

```
q1 = Document.all().run(prefetch_size=20, batch_size=20, limit=20, offset=0)
q2 = Document.all().run(prefetch_size=45, batch_size=45, limit=45, offset=20)
q3 = Document.all().run(prefetch_size=45, batch_size=45, limit=45, offset=65)
q4 = Document.all().run(prefetch_size=45, batch_size=45, limit=45, offset=110)
q5 = Document.all().run(prefetch_size=45, batch_size=45, limit=45, offset=155)
for i,d in enumerate(q1):        
    out += '<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>' % (d.title, d.lastEditedBy.name)
for i,d in enumerate(q2):        
    out += '<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>' % (d.title, d.lastEditedBy.name)
for i,d in enumerate(q3):        
    out += '<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>' % (d.title, d.lastEditedBy.name)
for i,d in enumerate(q4):        
    out += '<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>' % (d.title, d.lastEditedBy.name)
for i,d in enumerate(q5):        
    out += '<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>' % (d.title, d.lastEditedBy.name)
```

I apologize for my crummy python; but the idea is simple.  set your prefetch_size = batch_size = limit, and start all your queries at once.  q1 has a smaller size because we will block on it first, and blocking is what wastes time.  By the time q1 is done, q2 will be done or almost done, and q3-5 you will pay zero latency.

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/async#Async_Queries for details.

Comment: Thank you. This is interesting but I hope I will not need to do these kinds of hacks in order to make my application perform reasonably

Comment: This isn't really a hack.  This is how you unlock the power of appengine.  It can comfortably do 5-10 queries in parallel, and you can wrap this up in a single method def multiquery(...).  I do this all the time in appengine java, and dropped our cost from $70/day to $25/day.

Use asynchronous everything.  All appengine services can be used asynchronously, which is how you cut your instance hours to a minimum.

Comment: Also, if your DocUser reference property is causing expensive repeated gets() on the same entity, you should consider caching the keys of each lookup property while you are iterating, and then resolve only the unique keys, so you are only getting one at once.  I would recommend doing this asynchronously as well; if possible.

Comment: Thank you again. I have been thinking a bit about this and one thing I do not understand is how this technique could be applied if one does not know anything about the number of entities that will be returned. How did you implement that in your  multiquery(...) method?

Comment: The best use would be to have multiquery take an offset and pageSize parameter.  Use the pageSize query to determine how big to make each page, then use the offset so you can pick up where you left off.  If you expect 10000 entities, multiquery 2000 at a time, with ~5 pages of ~400 entities each.  Each time you call multiquery, send along an updated offset, and add it to each query.

Comment: Note that offsets aren't terribly efficient in appengine.  A better option would be to use query cursors; I'm not sure what python cursor support is like, but you can make your own easily for queries, based on your indexes.  If you already have a sort order on a field where every value is unique, just use the last returned value and add a query filter to continue where you left off [instead of sending offset to multiquery, just send the field name, value and sort direction].  If you don't have any sort orders, just sort by key. If you have sort orders on columns with repeats, add sort by key.

Comment: The whole idea of cursors is to be able to use the cursor to define a query that can use a > or < filter and a sort order, to be able to pick up where a previous query left off.  You can pass around a context object to be able to break huge queries into smaller queries.  If you usually have less than 1000 entities, you can just pick any page size like 100-200 to get good performance; if you have 100000, you have to perform paged requests, and should test how large your pages can be before performance gets slow or flaky.

Comment: Alternatively one could first run both a count query and a query for the X first results asynchronous. If the count is more than X, additional sliced queries could be run in parallel and results combined with the first query. If X is smaller results from the first query would simply be returned.  Further reduction of latency could maybe be achieved by  initially starting Y asynchronous sliced queries that in sum add up to X and combining these results  with additional queries based on the result of the count query if necessary. This could all be handled by the function based on the size of X.

Comment: You got it! =}  Although, beware using count queries, appengine charges one small operation per entity counted.  At $0.01/million, it's not a terribly big deal, but, in some cases {when you don't need to retrieve the entire data set, but still want to do efficient slices}, you could do a count query with limit=1 and offset=max_page_size to determine if there are many or few entities to retrieve.  The added complexity may not be worth it, and it is much easier to do sliced queries when you actually know the count.  All in all, it can cut query runtime dramatically.