# How to optimize one-to many queries in the datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-2.7

I have a latency problem in my application due to the datastore doing additional queries for referenced entities. I have received [good advice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10368312/1010991) on how to handle this for single value properties by the use of the get_value_for_datastore() function. However my application also have one-to many relationships as shown in the code below,  and I have not found a way to prefetch these entities. The result is  an unacceptable latency when trying to show a table of 200 documents and their associated documentFiles (>6000ms).

(There will probably never be more than 10.000 Documents or DocumentFiles)

Is there a way to solve this?

*models.py*

```
class Document(db.Expando):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    lastEditedBy = db.ReferenceProperty(DocUser, collection_name = 'documentLastEditedBy')  
...

class DocUser(db.Model):
    user = db.UserProperty()
    name = db.StringProperty()  
    hasWriteAccess= db.BooleanProperty(default = False)
    isAdmin = db.BooleanProperty(default = False)
    accessGroups = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
...

class DocumentFile(db.Model):
    description= db.StringProperty()
    blob = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
    created = db.DateTimeProperty() # needs to be stored here in relation to upload / download of everything    
    document = db.ReferenceProperty(Document, collection_name = 'files')

    @property
    def link(self):     
        return '<a href="/file/serve/%s">%s</a>' % (self.key().id(),self.blob.filename) 
...
```

*main.py*

```
docUsers = DocUser.all()
docUsersNameDict = dict([(i.key(), i.name) for i in docUsers])

documents = Document.all()
for d idocuments:        
    out += '<td>%s</td>' % d.title    
    docUserKey = Document.lastEditedBy.get_value_for_datastore(d)
    out +='<td>%s</td>' % docUsersNameDict.get(docUserKey)
    out += '<td>'                           
    # Creates a new query for each document, resulting in unacceptable latency
    for file in d.files: 
        out +=  file.link + '<br>'
    out += '</td>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denormalize and store the link in your Document, so that getting the link will be fast.

You will need to be careful that when you update a DocumentFile, you need to update the associated Document.  This operates under the assumption that you read the link from the datastore far more often than you update it.

Denormalizing is often the fix for poor performance on App Engine.

Comment: Thanks. Denormalizing it is then. It is a bit demoralizing  not being able to use the clean design promised in the docs but that is how life  sometimes are.

Answer (score 1):

Load your files asynchronously.  Use get_value_for_datastore on d.files, which should return a collection of keys, which you can then do db.get_async(key) to return a future object.  You will not be able to write out your result procedurally as you have done, but it should be trivial to assemble a partial request / dictionary for all documents, with a collection of pending future gets(), and then when you do your iteration to build the results, you can finalize the futures, which will have finished without blocking {~0ms latency}.

Basically, you need two iterations.  The first iteration will go through and asynchronously request the files you need, and the second iteration will go through, finalize your gets, and build your response.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/async

Comment: Thanks but get_value_for_datastore just returns an Query object  - Document.files.get_value_for_datastore(d) - so that will not work.

Comment: If full queries are too expensive for iterating that query, might I suggest using projection queries to return just the 'link' property?

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Query_Projection

query.fetch(projection=('links')) or query.run(projection=('links')) will, provided links is an indexed field, return a much faster query.  I still think you should be able to access the keys of the files you want without running a query; they must be returned in your document somewhere...